# Rigidbody2D keeps rotating when freeze position is checked

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, rigid-bodies

I'm making a brawl game, the arena is in space, so i followed a slippery movement script, and i made the characters rotate when player press A or D, but the rotating stops as soon as the player stops pressing A or D, i want the characters to keep rotating for 2sec before stopping, so i made a check when player last pressed A or D, and i also made it checked if player was not pressing any keys, and so if player last pressed A or D it will rotate in A or D direction for 2sec and freeze, but its not freezing

here's the rotating script

[image]

Here's the result

[image]

the z is checked but it's still rotating

Comment: pos the code, not the images of the code

Comment: Do **NOT** rotate the object using `transform.Rotate` this breaks the physics and is most likely the cause of your unexpected behavior .. rather use a.g. [`Rigidbody2D.AddTorque`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddTorque.html) or [`Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MoveRotation.html)

Answer (score 0):

The freeze option of the rigidbody handles/freezes the rotation regarding the physics, this is when a force is applied and you have forces, inertias etc. If you move the transform direcctly in the code this is not the case so the rigidbody component does not freeze/handle that approach. You should define the gameObject movement either moving the element directly moving its transform with code, or adding forces and letting the rigidbody handle the movement, but not both.

Comment: This is the same answer I wrote before

Comment: @Leoverload rustyBucketBay's answer was written 7 minutes prior to yours...

Comment: I love copy paste though

Comment: I'm sorry, I opened the question and there was no answer yet. So I searched for the unity doc to add the reference while leaving the tab opened and then I published the answer. When I saw your answer like 2 hours later I only saw "2 hours ago" and so I thought it was after mine. I should see the precise time but at the moment I didn't now where to find the exact moment. Sorry again!

Comment: no problem ;). Take into account that questions that are easy to answer will get fast plenty of answer proposals with what cuuld be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `FreezeRotation` of the rigidbody has this definition:
If `freezeRotation` is enabled, the rotation is not modified by the physics simulation.
But it seems like you are rotating the object with the script ( even if I don't see that part in your photo).
If you want to rotate the object only with script and not with gravity or physics you should always set has true `freezeRotation` and control the rotation only with the script with a `transform.Rotation = Quaternion.Euler()` and stop it with the same method. Physics will never change rotation and you will decide how to stop it